# Preview image on desktop without frame

Tags: desktop-customization

I am on a windows 7 machine.  My image is a png with a transparent background.  What I would like to do is show the image on my desktop without a frame. (preview, paint, browser).

Not to say that any program is out just I do not want the widows frame behind it. So that its just a freestanding movable image.

Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: Are you talking about that _shadowed_ framed like [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8FAEB.png)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a link that explains [how to use Frameless](http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/19/windows/image-photo/borderless-image-viewer.html), a command-line freeware utility that allows you to display a graphic...well...frameless. :-)

It supports PNG with transparency, but I was unable to find a way to show what's underneath the window. In other words, the program shows a white background. You can assign how transparent you want to make the Frameless window with the `trans=x` parameter. I used `trans=128` (valid values are 0-255) and I was able to see the windows underneath Frameless. Lots of options (see the README.TXT) that comes with the program) and light on resources (portable app, no installation necessary)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 has the ability to do a preview only if explorer is opened. If you open up a new explorer window and browse to your desktop, on the top right hand side of the explorer window you'll notice an icon to the left of help. If you click that icon, you'll get a preview pane in your explorer window that'll give you a live preview of files that you have highlighted.

Not quite frameless like OS X's preview but it's a start.